# if cell contains textA then numberA if another textB then numberB

Tags: google-sheets

I need to transform text in a cell to numeric value. The text is typed so I need to ingrore capitals and spaces. Ideally to use if cell `contains`

- text `car` = 350
- text `Mobile data` = 120
- text `car, mobile data` = 350 + 120
- text `mobile data,car` = 120 + 350

can I do that by one formula? Not by google script.

**UPDATE**

the final working solutin is

`=350 * regexmatch(lower(A2), "car") + 120 * regexmatch(lower(A2), "mobile data")`

so the replaced numbers can be summed

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your expected result is a text string like `120 + 350`, try this:

`=regexreplace( regexreplace( regexreplace( regexreplace( lower(trim(A2)), "car", "350" ), "mobile data", "120" ), "\s*,\s*", " + " ), "[^+\d ]", "" )`

If that is not what you wanted, please follow Rubén's advice, show your expected results, and also consider [The correct way to publicly share a Google test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).

Comment: It does exactly what I wanted. Just ... it does not work in my original sheet. It gives me `formula error`. I am not able to reproduce it so I can share it. https://i.imgur.com/QGsVO8V.png

Comment: If your spreadsheet is in a locale that uses semicolons `;` as formula argument separators, replace all commas `,` in the formula with semicolons `;`, except the one in `"\s*,\s*"`.

Comment: OMG, you are right. Thank you for that!!!

Comment: Now I need to sum the numbers so `120 + 350` becomes 470

Comment: Is this an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)? If you want `470`, you should have asked "how to get `470`" instead of asking "how to get `120 + 350`". Post a new question. See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [The correct way to publicly share a Google test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).

Comment: you are right. it was xy promblem from me. I got it now working thanks to you. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zlDb3NjNQi2A8tLY0dcX012ErM1gFnF_aGt85ARoUz4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: To get `470`, use `=350 * regexmatch(lower(A2), "car") + 120 * regexmatch(lower(A2), "mobile data")`.

Comment: I saw you working on it. Nice, elegant solution. Do you want me to create new question it would be wast of the solution otherwise

Comment: No, I do not think that would be necessary.